# Mysql few left join duplicate results

Tags: mysql, left-join

The results of the two left joins are duplicated as many times as the record in the second left join
A problem occurs when there is more than one left join.

How can I edit it to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance.

```
    SELECT
            `p`.*,
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`pi`.`id`, '-', `pi`.`img_path`) SEPARATOR ',') AS `images`,
            GROUP_CONCAT(`fp`.`filter_id` SEPARATOR \',\') AS `filter_options`
        FROM
            `products` AS `p`
        LEFT JOIN
            `product_images` AS `pi` ON (`pi`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`)
        LEFT JOIN
            `filters_products` AS `fp` ON (`fp`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`)
        WHERE
            `p`.`id` = ?
        GROUP BY
            `p`.`id`
```

Comment: Are there any duplicate IDs in `product_images` table?

Comment: product_id is on each row in both tables to know which product is in question

Comment: I am saying are they duplicates?

Comment: You can't legally select all columns from `products` and only group by `id`, what happens if you only select `p.Id`

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that if left joins are having multiple rows with given ID, results in group_concat will be multiplied also. There are several ways to tackle this problem, but likely easiest way is to use DISTINCT keyword. Although, it won't work correctly if it's intended that results could have multiple similar values. Another approach would be using subqueries instead of joins.

Here is an example use of DISTINCT in given query:

```
SELECT
            `p`.*,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(`pi`.`id`, '-', `pi`.`img_path`) SEPARATOR ',') AS `images`,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `fp`.`filter_id`  SEPARATOR \',\') AS `filter_options`
        FROM
            `products` AS `p`
        LEFT JOIN
            `product_images` AS `pi` ON (`pi`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`)
        LEFT JOIN
            `filters_products` AS `fp` ON (`fp`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`)
        WHERE
            `p`.`id` = ?
        GROUP BY
            `p`.`id`
```

Comment: True, I modified the answer

Answer (score -1):

This solved the problem.

Tnx to all

```
    SELECT
        `p`.*, `pi`.`images`, `fp`.`filter_options`
    FROM
        `products` AS `p`
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            `product_id`,
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`id`, '-', `img_path`) SEPARATOR ',') AS `images`
        FROM
            `product_images`
        GROUP BY
            `product_id`
    ) AS `pi` ON (`pi`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            `product_id`,
            GROUP_CONCAT(`filter_id` SEPARATOR ',') AS `filter_options`
        FROM
            `filters_products`
        GROUP BY
            `product_id`
    ) AS `fp` ON (`fp`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`)
    WHERE
        `p`.`id` = ?
    GROUP BY
        `p`.`id`
```